# TensorFlow - which model to build?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

We are creating a meta-search for realEstate. I would like to predict the running time (time the listing will be online) based on certain metrics with tensorflow.js sequential model.

I have following data:

```
  listing.buyingPrice,
  listing.foreClosure ? 1 :0,
  listing.leasehold ? 1 : 0,
  listing.squareMeter,
  listing.rooms,
  listing.grossReturn,
  listing.locationFactor.score
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
const createModel = () => {
  // Create a sequential model
  const model = tf.sequential();

  // Add a single hidden layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [shapeLength], units: 50, useBias: true}));


  // Add an output layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, useBias: true}));

  return model;
};


async function trainModel(model, inputs, labels) {
  // Prepare the model for training.
  const learningRate = 0.0001;
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(learningRate),
    loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
    metrics: ['mse'],
  });

  const batchSize = 32;
  const epochs = 50;

  return await model.fit(inputs, labels, {
    batchSize,
    epochs,
    shuffle: true
  });
}


const shapeLength=7;
const convertListing = (listing) => ([
  listing.buyingPrice,
  listing.foreClosure ? 1 :0,
  listing.leasehold ? 1 : 0,
  listing.squareMeter,
  listing.rooms,
  listing.grossReturn,
  listing.locationFactor.score
]);

const convertToTensor =(listings) => {
  // Wrapping these calculations in a tidy will dispose any
  // intermediate tensors.

  return tf.tidy(() => {
    // Step 1. Shuffle the data
    tf.util.shuffle(listings);

    // Step 2. Convert data to Tensor
    const inputs = listings.map(listing =>
      convertListing(listing)
    );
    const labels = listings.map(listing => listing.runningTime);

    const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, shapeLength]);
    const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels, [labels.length, 1]);

    return {
      inputs: inputTensor,
      labels: labelTensor,
    }
  });
};

const modelCreated = createModel();

export const doTraining = async () => {
  const listings = await findExactMatch({
    rented:false,
    active:false,
    zip:'10243',
  }, OBJECT_TYPES.APARTMENTBUY);

  const filteredListings = listings.filter(listing =>
    listing.runningTime>=0
    && listing.buyingPrice>=0
    && listing.runningTime <100
    && listing.rooms>0
    && listing.squareMeter >0
    && listing.grossReturn >0
    && listing.locationFactor.score>0
  );
  const tensorData = convertToTensor(filteredListings);
  const {inputs, labels} = tensorData;
// Train the model
  await trainModel(modelCreated, inputs, labels);
  console.log('Done Training');

  filteredListings.map(listing=>{
    console.log(listing.runningTime)
  });
  for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    console.log('Real running time',filteredListings[i].runningTime)
    console.log('Predicted runningTime',await testModel(filteredListings[i],tensorData));
  }

};

export const testModel = async (listing) => {

    const input = convertListing(listing);
    const inputData = tf.tensor2d([input], [1, shapeLength]);


  const result = modelCreated.predict(inputData);
  return result.dataSync()[0];
}
```

I'm using roughly 3000 listings. Problem is, that the running time I get predicted is WAY off. What to do to improve that? Is my model even correct? :)

Comment: I think you should reconsider this model

Comment: Can you give me some hints? :)